# Ubuntu update manager

Tags: server

I was downloading updates on update manager. It said I needed to get things to support this operation and should get a terminal and put in

```
apt-get install -f
```

I am not very good on a computer and do not have a clue how to do this.

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

If you working on a server, than you should have already an open terminal.

If not, open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T

After that, run the command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

More information with `man apt-get`. In a terminal ;)